# Downloading a URL results in an old file

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I'm having kind of a strange problem. I wrote this code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] raw;
string webData;                            
try
{
    raw = wc.DownloadData(host + "/get_transactions?UPDATE=" + Application.ProductVersion);
    webData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
    level = Convert.ToDouble(webData.Substring(0, webData.IndexOf("|")));
    if (level > Convert.ToDouble(Application.ProductVersion))
    {
        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("New Version found, Download?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;       
                client.DownloadFile(host + "/update.exe", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Update.exe");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

It is supposed to download a file from some URL (working fine).
The weird problem is that I've changed this file in my server and it has a different icon and size now.
 My application is still downloading the old file for some reason. I've opened my link in Chrome and Internet Explorer and they are downloading the old file too.
However, on other systems the link is working fine and the new file can be downloaded. Is there some kind of caching mechanism involved? if yes, how can I invalidate/clear it?
I'm using windows 10

Comment: Do you know if there is a server side cache? I think each browser has his own cache, so it's strange you get the old file in IE and Chrome. You can force a reload in Chrome by pressing Ctrl+F5.
If you don't find a solution, it will probably resolve itself after a few minutes/hours.

Comment: @Coder14 I have already tried that and it still yields the same result. Even installed a download manager to test and the results were the same.

Comment: Is this running over the Internet?  It is possible a proxy has cached the image inappropiately.